# If $f(3x-1)=9x^2+6x-7$, determine $f(x)$

Tags: functions

if $f(3x-1)=9x^2+6x-7$ determine all the $f(x)$ functions. 
I tried in this way :
$t=3x-1 \Rightarrow x=(t+1)/3$
$f(t)=9(t+1)^2/9-6((t+1)/3)-7((t+1)/3)\ldots$
but unfortunately I get the original function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not get the original function after substituting.  However you did make a mistake in substitution, in the last (constant) term, which just remains -7 after substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your method, substituting $t = 3x - 1 \iff x = \dfrac {t+1}{3} $, we have $$\begin{align} f(t) & = \dfrac{9(t+1)^2}{9} + \dfrac{6(t+1)}{3} - 7 \\ \\ & = (t+1)^2  +2(t+1) - 7 \\ \\ &= t^2 + 4t - 4 \end{align}$$

Hence, $$f(x) = x^2 + 4x - 4$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I doubt wether it is correct in the sense that t≠x (t=3x-1) .

Comment: Liviu - This is indeed correct. You use the substitution to determine what $f(x)$ is by using a "dummy variable" t. Use the final equation, and evaluate $f(3x - 1)$ by substituting $3x - 1$ everywhere you see $x$ in $f(x) = x^2 + 4x - 4$, and you'll get the original equation, $f(3x-1)$.

Comment: amWhy, thank you very much !

Comment: I learned something too. This method is nice. My method was over complicated and thus not worth publishing. My question is though after some experimenting, how would you approach such a problem if t cannot be expressed in terms of x? Or does that fall outside the boundaries of "doable"?